# chemfig chemname alignment, chemnameinit doesn't seem to do anything?

Tags: vertical-alignment, chemfig

I'm trying to get the chemical names to align vertically in this reaction, but for some reason setting `\chemnameinit` to match the larger molecule doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
    \chemnameinit{\chemfig{C(-[6]CH_2OPO_3^{2-})(-[4]H)(-[0]OH)(-[2]C(=[1]O)(-[3]H))}}
\schemestart[0,2.5,thick]  %argument specifies arrow angle, length, style
    \chemname{\chemfig{C(=[0]O)(-[2]CH_2OH)(-[6]CH_2OPO_3^{2-})}}{Dyhydroxyacetone phophate}
    \arrow{<=>[Triose phophate isomerase]}
    \chemname{\chemfig{C(-[6]CH_2OPO_3^{2-})(-[4]H)(-[0]OH)(-[2]C(=[1]O)(-[3]H))}}{D-Glyceradldehyde 3-phophate}
\schemestop
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use anchors on your arrow: when you remove the arrow, the two structures align on the central carbon. So, changing the definition of your arrow to

```
\arrow(.base east--.base west){<=>[Triose phophate isomerase]}
```

gives you the alignment on the central carbons. So the full example would be:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}         
    \chemnameinit{%
        \chemfig{C(-[6]CH_2OPO_3^{2-})(-[4]H)(-[0]OH)(-[2]C(=[1]O)(-[3]H))}}
    \schemestart[0,2.5,thick][north]  %argument specifies arrow angle, length, style
    \chemname{%
         \chemfig{C(=[0]O)(-[2]CH_2OH)(-[6]CH_2OPO_3^{2-})}}%
              {Dyhydroxyacetone phophate}
    \arrow%
        (.base east--.base west)% <----ensures alignment on baseline
        {<=>[Triose phophate isomerase]}
    \chemname{%
         \chemfig{C(-[6]CH_2OPO_3^{2-})(-[4]H)(-[0]OH)(-[2]C(=[1]O)(-[3]H))}}%
              {D-Glyceradldehyde 3-phophate}
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

(As an aside, it's considered good form here to give a complete code example, from `\documentclass{...}` to `\end{document}` to make it easier for others to compile your example and see what goes wrong (and play with it to find a solution)

Comment: Thanks @remco.
Where does the \documentclass and \end{document} come from?  I'm using texmath within libreoffice, and I suspect these are handled behind the scenes.

Comment: I had to add the extra lines to get an example that compiles with LaTeX compiler, assuming that that's what you used